# Why are empty classes 8 bytes and larger classes always > 8 bytes?

Tags: d

```
class foo { }

writeln(foo.classinfo.init.length); // = 8 bytes
```

---

```
class foo { char d; }

writeln(foo.classinfo.init.length); // = 9 bytes
```

Is d actually storing anything in those 8 bytes, and if so, what? It seems like a huge waste, If I'm just wrapping a few value types then the the class significantly bloats the program, specifically if I am using a lot of them. A char becomes 8 times larger while an int becomes 3 times as large.

A struct's minimum size is 1 byte.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In D, object have a header containing 2 pointer (so it may be 8bytes or 16 depending on your architecture).

The first pointer is the virtual method table. This is an array that is generated by the compiler filled with function pointer, so virtual dispatch is possible. All instances of the same class share the same virtual method table.

The second pointer is the monitor. It is used for synchronization. It is not sure that this field stay here forever, because D emphasis local storage and immutability, which make synchronization on many objects useless. As this field is older than these features, it is still here and can be used. However, it may disapear in the future.

Such header on object is very common, you'll find the same in Java or C# for instance. You can look here for more information : http://dlang.org/abi.html

Answer (score 9):

D uses two machine words in each class instance for:

1. A pointer to the virtual function table. This contains the addresses of virtual methods. The first entry points towards the class's [classinfo](http://dlang.org/property.html#classinfo), which is also used by dynamic casts.
2. The monitor, which allows the `synchronized(obj)` syntax, documented [here](http://dlang.org/statement.html#SynchronizedStatement).

These fields are described in the D documentation [here](http://dlang.org/class.html) (scroll down to "Class Properties") and [here](http://dlang.org/abi.html) (scroll down to "Classes").

Comment: Good, you answer is more concise than mine and provide the same information. I guess you deserve your +1 :D

Comment: You did beat me by 5 seconds ;)

Comment: Is the monitor used only for synchronization, or does it serve other purposes too?  If the former, spending four bytes on every object whether or not it will be synchronized upon seems needlessly wasteful (compared with e.g. requiring that objects used as monitors must derive from `MonitorObject`).  I like .net's approach, which uses a 32-bit field that encodes a few bits plus *either* an index into an "extra object info" table *or* an arbitrary immutable value generated by `GetHashCode`.  If an object's first use as a monitor follows its first call to `GetHashCode`...

Comment: ...the `GetHashCode` value generated by the foremr will be copied into its newly-allocated "extra-object-info" record.

Comment: It is used only for synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the particulars of D, but in both Java and .net, every class object contains information about its type, and also holds information about whether it's the target of any monitor locks, whether it's eligible for finalization cleanup, and various other things.  Having a standard means by which all objects store such information can make many things more convenient for both users and implementers of the language and/or framework.  Incidentally, in 32-bit versions of .net, the overhead for each object is 8 bytes except that there is a 12-byte minimum object size.  This minimum stems from the fact that when the garbage-collector moves objects around, it needs to temporarily store in the old location a reference to the new one as well as some sort of linked data structure that will permit it to examine arbitrarily-deep nested references without needing an arbitrarily-large stack.

**Edit**
If you want to use a class because you need to be able to persist references to data items, space is at a premium, and your usage patterns are such that you'll know when data items are still useful and when they become obsolete, you may be able to define an array of structures, and then pass around indices to the array elements.  It's possible to write code to handle this very efficiently with essentially zero overhead, provided that the structure of your program allows you to ensure that every item that gets allocated is released exactly once and things are not used once they are released.

If you would not be able to readily determine when the last reference to an object is going to go out of scope, eight bytes would be a very reasonable level of overhead.  I would expect that most frameworks would force objects to be aligned on 32-bit boundaries (so I'm surprised that adding a byte would push the size to nine rather than twelve).  If a system is going have a garbage collector that works better than a Commodore 64(*), it would need to have an absolute minimum of a bit of overhead per object to indicate which things are used and which aren't.  Further, unless one wants to have separate heaps for objects which can contain supplemental information and those which can't, one will every object to either include space for a supplemental-information pointer, or include space for all the supplemental information (locking, abandonment notification requests, etc.).  While it might be beneficial in some cases to have separate heaps for the two categories of objects, I doubt the benefits would very often justify the added complexity.

(*) The Commodore 64 garbage collector worked by allocating strings from the top of memory downward, while variables (which are not GC'ed) were allocated bottom-up.  When memory got full, the system would scan all variables to find the reference to the string that was stored at the highest address.  That string would then be moved to the very top of memory and all references to it would be updated.  The system would then scan all variables to find the reference to the string at the highest address below the one it just moved and update all references to that.  The process would repeat until it didn't find any more strings to move.  This algorithm didn't require any extra data to be stored with strings in memory, but it was of course dog slow.  The Commodore 128 garbage collector stored with each string in GC space a pointer to the variable that holds a reference and a length byte that could be used to find the next lower string in GC space; it could thus check each string in order to find out whether it was still used, relocating it to the top of memory if so.  Much faster, but at the cost of three bytes' overhead per string.

Comment: In D, I believe, it uses TLS so no locks are required but I guess that overhead is type info and other "junk" (would be nice to know what it is and to be able to get rid of it if possible).

Comment: @jsmdnq: There are substantial advantages to having all *class* objects include information about their type.  If you don't need any of the extra features a class would have, why not declare a struct?

Comment: Structs are value types and could be costly to pass around vs pointers for classes. They also do not allow custom default constructors. I understand there are advantages in many cases but not all cases. If I'm just wrapping a value with some methods(without inheritance/virtual functions) then all the class types and vtable space is just wasted. I do realize it would be very risky as is so maybe another type is needed?

Comment: @jsmdnq If you just need to wrap a value with some methods, then you don't really need a custom default c'tor or polymorphism - and you can use structs. If you worry about them being too costly to pass around, you can usually pass by const reference. Also, if your data structure contains so much data that it's actually expensive to blit-copy it - then those 8 bytes of class header should not bother you that much...

Comment: @IdanArye Sometimes you want to be able to be able to initialize the values properly. The pass by reference is costly in that, AFAIK, structs are generated on the stack and can keep other data around. While it's possible to create a struct on the heap it it makes things much more difficult in the long road(it is sort of a solution but I hope you don't forget to pass it by ref!).  You might be right on the last point as I'm not sure where the break even point is.

Comment: @jsmdnq: At least in .net, the decision between a struct or a class should usually be made on the basis of semantics. No type--whether class or struct--can control the default value for storage locations of that type; storage locations of all types default to all-bits-zero. An all-bits-zero class-type variable is a null reference, while an all-bits-zero struct-type variable holds a struct whose fields are all-bits-zero.  Does D allow any type to specify than an array of that type should be initialized to something else?

Comment: I'm simply talking about the syntax. Structs do not have a parameterless constructor to initialize fields with. This means all fields will be 0 when a struct type is instantiated. Classes have this() { } to set the fields to whatever they want.  For example, what if one field is the divisor? 0 is a very bad value to have it initialized to. In any case, it seems I'll end up having to either use structs or try and find a way to use a larger class containing all the values to do what I want. Basically I would like to override the opAssign on fields to notify listeners.

Comment: using a struct/class as a wrapper and `alias [value] this` is perfect for that. Unfortunately classes have all that overhead for small types and structs make it difficult to pass by reference(which I need to do to make things easier to sync and store). Passing structs by ref is probably the way to go but one slip and forgetting to add a ref modifier and things are all downhill.

Comment: @jsmdnq: If `foo` is a class type, and one creates an array `bar` of type `foo[]` and length 100, can elements of that array default to anything more useful than they could with a struct type, or are they all going to be `null`?  If D is like .net, then unless you have a struct whose natural default values represent something useful, array slots aren't going to be useful until they're explicitly written regardless of whether one uses a struct or a class.

Comment: @jsmdnq While you can't overwrite a default constructor for structs - you can set default values for each field. Usually this is enough.

Comment: @IdanArye yeah, it might work for my application as I won't need any logic for value type aliasing. Well, at least since the types are wrapped I can move any init code into the constructor of the main class, which if I'm careful to use the ref's should make everything work. Thanks, I'll play around with the idea and see if it will work better than using classes or not.

Answer (score -2):

You should look into the storage requirements for various types.  Every instruction, storage allocation (ie:variable/object, etc) uses up a specific amount of space.  In c# an Int32 type integer object should store integer information to the tune of 4 bytes (32bit).  It might have other information, too, because it is an object, but your character data type probably only requires 1 byte of information.  If you have constructs like for or while in your class, those things will take up space, too, because each of those things is telling your class to do something.  The class itself requires a number of instructions to be created in memory, which would account for the 8 initial bytes.

Take an assembler language course. You'll learn all you ever wanted to know and then some about why your programs use however much memory or take up however much storage when compiled.

Comment: Matt, while I respect that you're trying to provide some useful insights, your response is offtopic (it doesn't address the specific reasons why D class instances have a minimum size, but instead talks generally about data storage), and in some parts is misleading and poorly phrased (e.g. while/for loops taking up space in the instance: as a crude approximation, this is what a vtable does, but not in the sense that you're implying here.)

Comment: Actually, my response is pretty similar to deadalnix's.  Except I didn't realize D was a computer language (jsmdnq had a variable named d in his code and didn't capitalize in the question). Either way my point that a "class" has standard "stuff" in it that takes up space in addition to whatever methods or functions or variables it contains is correct.

Comment: Matt, unfortunately it's not like deadalnix's. You are addressing general things not applicable to the problem and many things are wrong. Class or struct objects do not store "code" inside them but only data(the fields). If you have a class or struct without any fields but a ton of methods then it will not take up any space(well, except 8 bytes in D, which is what the question pertained to). Why? Because a method is common to all objects(the code won't change) and it is stored outside the object itself. While it is true it will add to the size of the app it won't add to the size of object.

Comment: As was pointed out by a few, D stores a pointer to class info or a vtable which is required for inheritance when you override methods and  some way to associate type information with an *object*(which is just data).  When I wrote the question I forgot that D added that stuff to support it's type system.  I guess when I saw 8 bytes on a 32bit app I was shocked for no apparent reason except that I was using classes to wrap value types and it would severely bloat my program.